# Convergence of Random Variables 2

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

> If for sequences of random variables $d_n\geq0$ and $r_n>0$ 
>   $$ d_n=r_n \left(\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{1.5}}\right)\right) \text{   as    } n\to \infty   \,\,Eq.(1)$$
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} Pr\left( r_n \leq 2n\right)=1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,Eq.(2)$$
>   How can we conclude this?
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} Pr\left( d_n \leq 4\right)=1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,Eq.(3)$$

From Eq(1), if we could conclude  $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} Pr(d_n\leq \frac{r_n}{n})=1$, then we are done. But, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Not true, try deterministic $d_n=2+\frac1n$ and $r_n=2n$.

Comment: @Did Thanks. You are right. I edited Eq(3), since this also works for my original problem.

Comment: Next problem: which convergence mode underlies the limits in (1)?

Comment: @Did We know that $d_n = r_n (1/n+1/n^2+1/n^3+\cdots)$.

Comment: Ouch! Limit of $f(n)$ is $1/n$ (depending on $n$)? What does that even mean?

Comment: @Did Sorry, I edited my comment.

Comment: Huh? Then $d_n=r_n/(n-1)$ hence $P((n-1)d_n\leqslant2n)\to1$ and, since $2n/(n-1)\leqslant3$ for every $n\geqslant3$, one knows that...

Comment: If $d_n=r_n (1/n+1/n^2+\cdots)$, then $d_n=r_n/(1-1/n)$. So your argument will not work. Let me give you the exact relation between $d_n$ and $r_n$ which is $d_n=r_n (1/n+\mathcal{O}(1/n^{1.5})$ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44426/discussion-between-sus20200-and-did).

Comment: "If dn=rn(1/n+1/n2+⋯), then dn=rn/(1−1/n)." No, but $d_n=r_n/(n−1)$, as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: You are right! Sorry about it. Actually, the real relation between $d_n$ and $r_n$ is $d_n=r_n \left(\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{1.5}}\right)\right) \text{   as    } n\to \infty$ and the one I told you earlier was a special case of this. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: ?? As already mentioned, the mode of convergence in (1) should be made precise.

Comment: @Did It is Pointwise convergence